# Handling spaces in a URL

Tags: javascript

I have a function called x, which is a method of a plugin, but I have issue using variable for the param like below :

```
var q= 'adele rolling in the deep';
x('http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q='+q); // doesn't worked
```

I do `console.log('http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q='+q)` it give me 
`http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=adele rolling in the deep`, why the `+` is missing?

When I test with static url like below it worked

```
x('http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=adele+rolling+in+the+deep'); // worked
```

Comment: `+q` => `+encodeURIComponent(q)`

Comment: @dandavis, put that as the answer.

Comment: What are you try to do? Replace space with plus? Or make space work with url?

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your query as a URI component:

```
x('http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(q));
```

Some libraries may handle this for you, others will not. In this case, it looks like the library isn't handling it for you.

Comment: that still won't give you `+`s in the url, which might be a deal breaker to OP...

Comment: @dandavis - As long as the value is properly encoded, it shouldn't matter (`adele+rolling+in+the+deep` and `adele%20rolling%20in%20the%20deep` are parsed the same way by the server).

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple. In an URL, the space can be decoded into '%20' (look the ascii table) or more commonly into +. What you are doing here just a simple string addition, or combination. That means that if you have to string a and b following situation will occur:

```
var c = a + b
c -> ab (and you put for a and b the values that you defined before)
```

What you are doing up there is exactly the same. You just combine the strings without influencing their values. To get it into an url format you need to use:

```
x('http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(q));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple replace will do the trick:

```
x(('http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q='+q).replace(/ /g,'+'))
```

Easy Peasy.